# Building realistic simulation using differential equations

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, software, randomness

I am building simulation using differential equations to model the motion of a damped vertical spring-mass system. I wish to use this simulation to extract data. For example, I am trying to find the effect of mass on the damping.

The problem I am facing is every time I run the model, I receive the same numbers. Thus, I cannot run multiple trials. This makes sense because the model is purely iterative. How do I add a bit of randomness to the model to make it more realistic and usable for experimentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is **“you add randomness to the system parameters and initial conditions”**. Some search terms are “uncertainty quantification” and “design of experiments”.

But ... those techniques are used for models where there isn’t a detailed analytic understanding of the end-to-end behavior of the system. They would be wasteful overkill for the system in front of you.